# Android Studio Sqlite Database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Register.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "particulars_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "Email";
    public static final String COL_3 = "Username";
    public static final String COL_4 = "Password";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,EMAIL TEXT,USERNAME TEXT,PASSWORD TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Email VARCHAR, Username VARCHAR,Password VARCHAR);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String Email, String Username, String Password){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,Email);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,Username);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,Password);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

}
```

I have this code in my project, but I can't seem to get the table onto my database. When I checked my database in the developer file explorer, the database was created. Is there anything wrong with my code that prevents it from creating the table and accepting my inputs from my program to save the particulars?

Comment: I'm not sure but propably you have to insert data asynchronously

Comment: Did you heard of Room library? It will be much easier and clean.

Comment: I think. your onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) is wrong.

Comment: show your database in developer file explorer

Comment: @Gayathri Sorry Im not sure how to post an image in this post.I will explain to you.Basically now the database contains my previous databases that I created that screwed up,and now there's two new ones which are .......db-shm and .....db.wal

Comment: @JianMinOng db-shm and db.wal are temporary databases created by sqlite, these are not your db

Comment: check your code with -  https://www.javatpoint.com/android-sqlite-tutorial

Comment: @Gayathri I tried opening the database under "Browse Data" on DB Browser for SQLite. but its not showing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `db.execSQL` to

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE_NAME (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Email VARCHAR, Username VARCHAR,Password VARCHAR);");
```

the `$TABLE_NAME` will be replace with your `String TABLE_NAME = "particulars_table"` by your SqlHelper

Answer (score 0):

Try this to create table.

In below query there was no space between **EXISTS** and **Table-name** so it was **EXISTSTable** name.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,EMAIL TEXT,USERNAME TEXT,PASSWORD TEXT)");
```

OR 
In this you havn't added table name.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Email VARCHAR, Username VARCHAR,Password VARCHAR);");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your commented CREATE statement must be changed to this:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,EMAIL TEXT,USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT)"
```

you had no space before TABLE_NAME, so it produced this: 
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTSparticulars_table`.

In `onCreate()` change `db.execSQL()` to this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,EMAIL TEXT,USERNAME TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT)");
```

**Uninstall** the app from the emulator/device where you test it so that the db is deleted and run again.

Comment: what do you mean?do you mind writing out the solution?I am a beginner actually

Comment: Since the solutions given are the same which is the space.I've edited alr.So what is the best way to check whether I am doing the right thing and i want to see my database?

Comment: @JianMinOng as i said uninstall the db, run the app again and check if the table is now created

Comment: I've done so,ran the app on the emulator and now its not creating the database.do I have to wait or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Email VARCHAR, Username VARCHAR,Password VARCHAR);"); }
```

In this query table name is not specified. It maybe the reason that table not created.